# Getting/Setting File Permissions From Rebol

Tags: file-permissions, rebol, rebol3

Is it possible to change file permissions within Rebol 3 without relying on CALLing CHMOD? Rebol 2 had `'set-modes` though doesn't appear to be available any longer:

```
permissive-access: [
    owner-read: group-read: world-read:
    owner-write: group-write: world-write: #[true]
    owner-execute: group-execute: world-execute: #[false]
]

set-modes file permissive-access
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, no, you have to use `call`.

It is planned to add back the port mode getting and setting capabilities, but the API needs a revamp first and we haven't started the discussion for that yet. The port model is mostly different in Rebol 3, so the port mode model is going to have to be different too. Feel free to get the discussion started.